# how to retain exact numbers that come from Access Database

Tags: c, datagridview

MY scenario is... I have 6,000 datas in Excel Sheet.. I try to import to Access Database.It enters the Database like this..

UNit Price 34512.00   Vat 4.00

BUt when i Retrieve to DataGridColumn it Shows vat Rate as 4(whole number).I accept zeros has no values..But I need that to be displayed in Grid as 4.0  . How to achieve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm quite confused about the combination of tags `c` and `datagridview`, but I'm going to assume by the second tag you mean .NET WinForms DataGridView. In which case, you'll want to play with the `Format` property of the `DataGridViewColumn` to force it to show decimal places.

Comment: for (i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
{
  dvgproductlist.Rows[i].Cells[7].Value = dt.Rows[i]["UnitPrice"].ToString();
}
This how i retrieve values from access Database to gridview..
How can enable here the Format PROPERTY.

Comment: In that case, you want to use the built-in format capabilities of `ToString`. In this case, maybe something like `ToString("F1")` which will display as `4.0`.

Answer (score 1):

Use a format string, here is some reference [Standard Numeric Format Stings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx)

Comment: or (i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++) { dvgproductlist.Rows[i].Cells[7].Value = dt.Rows[i]["UnitPrice"].ToString(); } This how i retrieve values from access Database to gridview.. How can enable here the Format PROPERTY.How to achieve this